# Animate diagonal line query

Tags: jquery, css

I was wondering if anyone knows how to create a diagonal line using jquery and animate it so that when it appears its drawn on rather than just appears?

Also need the same for a circle.

A simple jsfiddle would be awesome.

Muchos for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually do it with pure CSS:

## [demo](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/AKBnL)

### Diagonal

**HTML**:

```
<div class='box'></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: dotted 1px;
  width: 8.09em; height: 5.88em;
  background: linear-gradient(36deg, 
                transparent 49.5%, black 49.5%, black 50.5%, transparent 50.5%) 
               no-repeat -8.09em -5.88em;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  animation: drawDiag 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes drawDiag {
  to { background-position: 0 0; }
}
```

---

### Circle

**HTML**:

```
<div class='circle'>
  <div class='cover'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.circle {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 10em; height: 10em;
}
.circle:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit; height: inherit;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px black;
  content: '';
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 -50%;
  width: 200%; height: inherit;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  background: white;
  animation: revealCircle 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes revealCircle {
  to { transform: rotate(180deg); }
}
```

Comment: Sexiness and perfect for what I am looking to do, bang tidy, thank you very much

Comment: OK, so I have all of the above working, great however I cannot get it doing what I want, I would ideally like to be able to change the angle without the line moving and so on, any ideas..?

I would like to change it to, say, 45 degrees and it not move outside of the demo?