# Animate a dotted diagonal line

Tags: css, css-animations

I used the 
[Animate diagonal line query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555186/animate-diagonal-line-query)
and it works perfectly.

I was trying to style the line so that I can make it dotted or dashed instead of one solid line. I've tried the dotted and dashed border attributes, but they only change the outer border and not the line itself.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: The solution in Animate diagonal line query uses a background gradient which is simply white on the outside and a thin black strip in the middle.  Then the animation moves the background from the negative offset to it's normal position.  You would not be able to use this solution exactly but you could replace the gradient with an image of a dotted/dashed line.

Comment: can you use svg? it's easy to animate a dashed line with svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built off cocoa's comment.  Draw a line with SVG, apply a mask over top, then animate the mask to reveal the line.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qORzbe

```
<div class="box">
    <svg height="200" width="200" class="line1">
        <line fill="none" stroke="black" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" stroke-dasharray="5, 5" />
    </svg>
    <div class="mask"></div>
</div>

.box {
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: dotted 1px;
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.mask {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    animation: showDiag 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showDiag {
    from { left: 0; top: 0; }
    to { left: 200px; top: 200px; }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This is just what I was looking for.